# How to configure Windows Authentication (NTLM, Negotiate) to work when using IISARR?

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, iis-10

As part of the upgrade from Win 2008 to Win 2016-project, we have introduced the use of DNS-aliases (way overdue) for all IIS-sites in all enviroments. We now use IIS with ARR installed as a proxy server in order to "hide" the servername:portnumber for the clients. 
All this is straight forward except for a service that is protected using Windows Authentication (NTLM, Negotiate). This is causing problems for all clients of that service that uses the DNS-alias (other services, Clickonce applications

- For all other clients than Internet Explorer on my laptop the cs_username field is empty in the logs.
- Accessing the service using Internet Explorer - cs_username contains my username and I'mlogged in (http 401, followed by http 200)
- Accessing the service using Chrome, I get a pop up requesting username password
- On a server logged on as my admin-id and adding the alias to  "Local Intranet" it did not help for Chrome, but on a server where I was logged on with my admin userid - it did enable IE to log on without uid/pwd.

Being all new to IIS and not being a developer, but an operations guy, I'm a bit lost at the moment on where I need to change stuff - in the Clickonce app, on the IIS ARR-server or on the server hosting the service?

## Topology

[image: Tolpology - simple overview]

Comment: How many IIS servers are involved ? ARR and the service protected by Authentication are on the same server ?

Comment: @Swisstone - Added a simple drawing of the topology. ARR is hosted on a dedicated server - with N-number of other IIS-servers in the back.